# Get Default Gateway from Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to return the Default Gateway like i have for the IPv4 but it returns Blank.

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~1%
echo.
echo  IP Address is: %ip%
echo.
```

This is what i have so far but it returns blank, i have tried to alter it but it still returns a blank answer.

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "Default"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~2%
echo.
echo  The Gateway is: %ip%
echo.
```

Any ideas how i can do this. and return the default gateway for a given Computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set "ip="
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "Default"') do if not defined ip set ip=%%b
```

Take a look at the listing from `ipconfig` - it's likely that there is more than one `default` line. You would therefore get the data from the `last` line containing `default`

The above construct returns the `first` line containing `default`.

Comment: right now it doesn't work as the gw ip is a space separated

Comment: @jlanza : This should work for strings containing spaces; just not for target string containing colons (which shouldn't be the case for the target circumstance.) Please create your own question and include a listing of your sample data - disguised if required. This version also retains a leading space which may or may not be significant.

Comment: When running this example the space is significant as the assignment in windows implies no space between = and variable. Just noticing that in comments as this is the accepted answer

Comment: Doesn’t work when an IPV6 address is also present, because the IPV4 address is displaced alone to the next line.

Comment: @BogeyJammer : My system, even today, correctly reports the default gateway IPv4 address and `ipconfig` displays no "displaced IPv4" address. Please post a new question showing the `ipconfig` listing that is shown for *you*

Comment: For people like _me_ whose ipconfig output lines get wraped probably because of a system langage different than _english_, I suggest Foxidrive’s answer which is more reliable.

Comment: @BogeyJammer : All fine and good - but, as has been repeated many times on SO - `WMIC is deprecated`. I cannot fix this solution without seeing the `ipconfig` listing that is shown for *you*.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a WMIC script:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%a in ('"WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled="True" get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do echo IPv4 %%~a IPV6 %%~b
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

### This worked for me.

Got first listed gateway.

```
@echo off
set "ip="
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%a in ('"WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled="True" get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do if not defined ip set ip=%%~a

echo  IP Mobile Address is: %ip%
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1-5" %%a in ('route -4 print 0.*'
) do @if "%%e"=="" if "%%a"=="%%b" set "ip=%%c"
```

This will extract the default gateway from the ipv4 route table.