# How do I ping the default gateway without specifying the IP address?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping

I'm trying to write a batch file that tests network connectivity by pinging the default gateway of the given network.
However, as I want this to be an automated process which then logs the results to a text file, I'd like to be able to ping the gateway on various networks, without having to change/enter the ip address.

Is there a generic term or command to ping the default gateway for the network you're currently connected to?

(I already have the commands for output options etc.)

So far, I have this....

```
@echo off
goto :NETWORK1

:NETWORK1
ipconfig
echo .
Set /P gateway=PLEASE ENTER GATEWAY IP ADDRESS (shown above): 
if /I "%gateway%" EQU "exit" goto :EXIT
if /I not "%gateway%" EQU "exit" goto :NETWORK2

:NETWORK2
echo CLOSING THIS WINDOW WILL ABORT THE CONNECTIVITY TEST.
echo . >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"
echo Time: >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"
time /t >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"
ping %gateway% -n 20 >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"
goto :NETWORK2

:EXIT
exit
```

But I don't want to have to specify the IP address, so that I can take away the need for user input.

Answer (score 1):

smalll fix for Wernfried Domscheit

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%g in ('netsh interface ip show address ^| findstr /c:"Default Gateway"') do ping %%g

pause
```

just adding /c: before "Default Gateway"

Answer (score 0):

On a command line you can try this one:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %g in ('netsh interface ip show address ^| findstr "Default Gateway"') do ping %g
```

Note, inside a batch-file you must double the `%`, i.e.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%g in ('netsh interface ip show address ^| findstr "Default Gateway"') do ping %%g
```

Comment: OK, so I gave that a try with the below code, and it gives the correct results on the first loop, but on all following loops, it just pings 0.0.0.0.....

`@echo off`
`goto :NETWORK`
`:NETWORK`
`echo . >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"`
`echo Time: >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"`
`time /t >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"`
`for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%g in ('netsh interface ip show        address ^| findstr "Default Gateway"') do ping %%g -n 20 >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"`

`goto :NETWORK`

Answer (score 0):

According to jimbobomcgee on serverfault who phrased the correct answer for the question [How to Extract command-line output into a Variable?](https://serverfault.com/questions/469053/how-to-extract-command-line-output-into-a-variable)

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %A in (`ipconfig ^| Find "Default Gateway" ^| Findstr/N "." ^| Findstr/B "1:"`) do @if not defined MYVAR set MYVAR=%~C
```

Comment: SO, I tried.... `for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %%A in (`ipconfig ^| Find "Default Gateway" ^| Findstr/N "." ^| Findstr/B "1:"`) do ping %%A -n 20 >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"` ... but it just brings pack the results of pinging 0.0.0.1

Comment: You cannot use `%%A` (only returns 1) - use `%~C`.

Did you try executing the above command (assuming that MYVAR is NOT set) and check its value afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "gateway="
    for /f "tokens=1-5" %%a in ('route -4 print 0.*') do @if "%%e"=="" if "%%a"=="%%b" set "gateway=%%c"
    if not defined gateway goto :eof

    echo CLOSING THIS WINDOW WILL ABORT THE CONNECTIVITY TEST.

:loop
    echo %date% %time%
    >> "Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt" (
        echo(
        echo(Time: %time%
        ping -n 20 -4 %gateway%
    )
    goto :loop
```

Gateway determination from `route` information copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374435/2861476)

**edited** for a more tolerant parse of the `route` command use

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('route -4 print 0.* ^| find "0."') do set "gateway=%%a"
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives absolutely no results whatsoever.

Comment: @jemisageek, please, remove the `@echo off` to see where it fails.

Comment: It still doesn't give me any results, or "feedback" as the command windows opens and closes almost instantly

Comment: Interface List
 16...74 2f 68 cd d7 fa ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 11...74 2f 68 cd 3d d4 ......Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

Comment: IPv4 Route Table
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254    192.168.1.229     25
Persistent Routes:
  None
IPv6 Route Table
Active Routes:
  None
Persistent Routes:
  None

Comment: So it looks like you're right about my lack of persistent routes. Unfortunately, you've gone above my knowledge base, so don't really know what that means or how to allow for it. I want the test to be carried out on the wireless adapter.

Comment: @jemisageek, in this case the solution is simple. The `if "%%e"==""` part is only checking that the line do not include an interface and a metric. Change the line so it ends `... ) do if "%%a"=="%%b" set "gateway=%%c"`, that is, just remove check on `%%e`

Comment: Sorry, so the line should read `for /f "tokens=1-5" %%a in ('route -4 print 0.*') do @if "%%e"=="" ... ) do if "%%a"=="%%b" set "gateway=%%c"`

Comment: @jemisageek, I've included and simplified (a lot simplified but enough for this problem) gw retrieval from `route` output.

Comment: @jemisageek, answer updated. If you get your code working, don't touch it, but there exist some problems with some windows localizations, i've updated the "simplified" check to prevent problems. Sorry for the dizziness of updates

Answer (score 0):

After help from @MC ND, I have created the following code, which does exactly what I needed....

1. pings the default gateway with the results being output to a text file
2. shows a message telling the user not to close the command window

`@echo off`

`setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion`

`for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('route -4 print 0.*') do set "gateway=%%a"`

`:NETWORK`

`echo CLOSING THIS WINDOW WILL ABORT THE CONNECTIVITY TEST.`

`echo Time >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"`

`time /t >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"`

`echo . >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"`

`ping %gateway% -n 20 >> "C:\Network Test Results %date:/=.%.txt"`

`goto :NETWORK`