# How to get last default gateway from a windows command file

Tags: windows, networking, command

In [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367173/get-default-gateway-from-batch-file) a script is presented to capture the last default gateway. (Another solution is shown to capture the *first* gateway, but I want the last one.

The script is:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "Default"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~2%
echo.
echo  The Gateway is: %ip%
echo.
```

Given this ipconfig input (some details removed for privacy):

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.251.148
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

Ethernet adapter Npcap Loopback Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::****:a19b:****:bf4%15
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.11.244
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ev***.li****.io
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a**:c4**:c**1:dfa3%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.100.17.34
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.100.16.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

c:\>
```

The output result is:

```
c:\>for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %a in ('ipconfig|find "Default"') do set ip=%b
c:\>set ip= 0.0.0.0
c:\>set ip=
c:\>set ip= 10.100.16.1
c:\>set ip=0.100.16.1
c:\>echo.
c:\>echo  The Gateway is: 0.100.16.1
 The Gateway is: 0.100.16.1
c:\>echo.
```

As the for loop iterates, it has the correct gateway address on the third iteration, but then a fourth iteration overwrites it with and incorrect value with the first digit truncated. I'm not sure why there is a fourth iteration since the word Default is present three times.

Why does this happen?

Comment: FYI, you do not need to obfuscate your Link-Local IPv6 addresses because they cannot be used off the link or routed, the same way that your IPv4 Link-Local address on the Ethernet adapter Npcap Loopback Adapter does not need to be obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks for the note on the addresses.  Any suggestions on why the script doesn't work?